# How can I define a directory in the source repository in a cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-functions

Define the directory where source code is stored in the source repository

Hi, I am creating a cloud function 2nd generation and I am using code from another source repository.
I am using Terraform and the module *"google_cloudfunctions2_function"*. In the *"repo_source"* I want to define a directory in *"dir"* where my *main* is stored. The file is stored in the root and then in the folder *parse_json*. My terraform piece of code for this looks as follows:

```
repo_source = {

  project_id  = var.project_id

  repo_name = "MY_REPO"

  branch_name   = "master"

  dir = "parse_json/"
}
```

Anyway, the source function is still pointing to the root and it is not recognising the folder *parse_json*.
What is the syntax for *"dir"* when my code is not in the root?

Answer (score 1):

The cloud functions v2 actually there is no support for Cloud Source Repositories yet.

Will be able to see it on this doc. [Google Cloud Functions Documenation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/version-comparison#coming_soon_in_2nd_gen)